# Mac programs to demo a video card?

Tags: macos, mac, video, graphics-card

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/32048/programs-to-demo-a-high-end-video-card), but it seems to be directed toward Windows. What are some Mac demo programs that will really push a video card to it's limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Benchmarking** applications.

**1**. [**XBench**](http://www.xbench.com/), and [a reference list](http://db.xbench.com/) for comparison.

[image]

**2**. [Maxon **Cinebanch**](http://www.maxon.net/index.php?id=162&L=0) and [reference list](http://www.3dfluff.com/mash/cinebench/top.php).

> MAXON CINEBENCH runs several tests on your computer to measure the performance of the main processor and the graphics card under real-world circumstances.

**3**. [Football Manager 2009](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/games/demos_updates/footballmanager2009.html) Game Demo.
You will find a lot of interesting demo downloads at the [Apple site](http://www.apple.com/downloads/).

**4**. If you have iTunes, the [**visualization** modes](http://www.usingmac.com/2008/11/4/funtastic-itunes-visualizers) would be good too.

---

An interesting story: [An Incredible Mac Pro Demo: Takes Breath Away](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/an_incredible_mac_pro_demo_takes_breath_away/)

> **One measure of the Mac is how many trailers it can play at once without any one of them stuttering**. When I was using a dual processor 800 MHz Mac Pro G4, the best I could do was about seven or maybe eight simultaneous trailers. It's been awhile since I did that demo, so I decided to revisit with a Mac Pro, Nehalem (March 2009), quad core, with 3GB of RAM, standard video card (NVIDIA GT120) and two displays attached.

Has a youtube link to a demo with [21 standard definition videos running at the same time](http://www.youtube.com/v/vC_HWNJFTjY&hl=en&fs=1).

---

The Spore site has [Mac **Trial demos**](http://www.spore.com/trial) for download.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, to "push a video card to it's [sic] limits" has two different meanings.

1. 3D-capabilities showcase
2. GPU processing showcase

For 3D-capabilities showcase, just grab the latest, bestest game demo. For now, I believe Call of Duty 4 will stress most machines. Even better, hook up a large external monitor and run it at max resolution.

For GPU processing showcase, I do not know of any program that taps on the new OpenCL APIs as of now, though you might want to give Quicktime X a shot at movie conversion. Rendering a movie with additional GPU processing on a Mac should speed up tremendously.

This said, these two will truly push the video card to its limits.

Answer (score 1):

ATI has [some Mac demos](http://ati.amd.com/developer/demos/macss2/index.html).